# Rust: take ownership of enum value without another pattern matching

Tags: enums, rust, match

The question is in the comment. `Expensive` is a struct that either doesn't implement `Copy`, or copying is too expensive.

**Update**: replaced `Option` with a user enum `Internal`.

```
enum Internal {
    Type1(Expensive),
    Type2(String),
    Empty,
}

struct Foo {
    value: Internal,
}

impl Foo {
    fn exec(&mut self) -> Result<Expensive, String> {
        if let Internal::Type1(_) = &self.value {
            let value = std::mem::take(&mut self.value);
            
            // QUESTION: how do I avoid this pattern matching since we know the value must be Internal::Type1
            return match value {
                Internal::Type1(e) => Result::Ok(e),
                _ => Result::Err(String::from("Impossible")),
            };
        }

        // Some other logic that will use self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass through the thing as-is? I don't think the `std::mem::take` is necessary. You should just get it if you unwrap the thing with `let`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to do `if let Option::Some(v) = self.value { return Result::Ok(v) }`?

Comment: @tadman I can't use "self.value" because self is a mutable reference "&mut self".

Comment: Well, you can't "take" it without mutating it.

Comment: @tadman That's why I need `std::mem::take`. Your code `if let Option::Some(v) = self.value { return Result::Ok(v) }` will result in this error: "cannot move out of `self.value.0` which is behind a mutable reference"

Comment: I'm under the impression that you can't move this unless a) you destroy `self` in the process, as in `fn exec(mut self) -> <...>`, or b) you swap it out with an empty version of same. What's wrong with consuming `self`?

Comment: Alternatively, why not remove `value` from `Foo` and instead generate it as a byproduct of the `exec` function rather than (temporarily?) stashing it there. I know this is an abbreviated version of the code, but this could very well be an XY Problem. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: I think that needs some kinds of "occurrence typing" in Racket or "smart cast" in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to make the code shorter:

```rust
if let Option::Some(value) = self.value.take() {
    return Ok(value);
}
```

Comment: I updated the code. The enum has more than two variants and I only want to take it when  it matches one variant.